# Unable to fill JTable component created with IntelliJ GUI Designer

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea, jtable

I have a JTable component I made in IntelliJ's GUI Designer. The class is bound to the GUI Form and compiles without problem, but the table stays empty. I've tried to use some other code as well, but im a bit new to java and really want to know the answer to this. please dont give me a half answer or point me to a page to go figure it out. I am here cause I did try that.

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * Created by User on 3/8/2016.
 */
public class TableGUI {
    private static JFrame frame;
    private JTable table1;
    private JPanel panel1;

    public TableGUI() {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

        table1.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        table1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table1.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(550, 200));
        model.addColumn("Id");
        model.addColumn("First Name");
        model.addColumn("Last Name");
        model.addColumn("Company Name");
        table1.setModel(model);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new JFrame("TableGUI");
        frame.setContentPane(new TableGUI().panel1);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
    }
}
```

Comment: You never add the JTable to the GUI. Components don't magically appear on the GUI --  you have to add them to it. Here you'd add your JTable to a JScrollPane (actually to its viewport) and add that to the panel1 variable.

Comment: You also don't seem to be adding anything to the table

Comment: The JTable component is made inside the GUI designer, its not made programmatically.... the TableGUI class is bound to the Swingform made in designer. I have seen threads where they specificcaly say dont add your own "new JTable()", because it would create another instance thats not bound to the GUI.

Comment: What Swingform??? The code you posted does not have a Swingform. The code you posted has a main() method that displays an empty JFrame. If you need more help you need to post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem because the code you posted does nothing.

Comment: I figured it out (partially), I added a row of data to my `DefaultTabelModel model`, like so: `model.addRow(new Object[] { "cell1", "cell2", "cell3", "cell4"});`. So my code works partially, but it doesnt show the column names... which supposedly only show with a `new JScrollPane()`. I dont know how to implement this on a JTable added via the designer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out, the answer was I was lacking a **JScrollPane**. I had to drop in a component called **JScrollPane** via the IntelliJ Designer and drop the **JTable** inside it. This allowed for the column-names to show on the JTable.

Comment: Wouldn't have known that without this answer